# How to clone a table with input and text areas?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code given below shows whenever a new button is clicked this code gets executed and the first row of .table_product_list table gets cloned but it only increases the input box's id and name

how to tweak this code to add text areas?

```
   var i=1;
    $(".table_product_list tr:first").clone().find("input").each(function() {
        $(this).attr({
         'id': function(_, id) { return id + i },
         'name': function(_, name) { return name + i },
         'value': ''               
        });
    }).end().appendTo(".table_product_list");
    i++;
```

Comment: You mean in the `find()` statement you want to include `textarea`, and in the `id, name` attributes, you don't want to change the id and name? I don't quite understand...

Comment: Sorry Found the answer ! its simple find("input,textarea")

Comment: If you found the solution yourself. Please consider answering you own question so you can share the knowledge with the world =)

Comment: Answer your question button isn't working !

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [JSfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/leslieCS/CKRPG/) to show the way I implemented the cloning of `TR`s with id and name change can be performed on any table row their addition and removal.

Hope that helps!